# Self Hosting Supabase: Twitter Provider Oauth issue

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js, supabase-py, supabase-realtime

how can i use twitter on self hosting instance on supabase? I read the docs but i don't found anything related to that concept. Also i look the docker compose and env files and i don't find any solution to that problem.

Any suggestions?

I tried this through the docs  https://github.com/supabase/gotrue#external-authentication-providers
by doing these changings in env of docker folder but it does not work out.
`GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_TWITTER_ENABLED=true GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_TWITTER_CLIENT_ID=myappclientid GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_TWITTER_SECRET=clientsecretvaluessssh GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/callback`